# Struts 2 text tag weird behavior

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, resourcebundle, ognl

I am using the Struts2 text tag, to get a translated value.
So, I have the following statement:

```jsp
<s:text name="a"/>
```

I don't have any key `'a'` in the properties files, but in the action, I have an object with name `a`.

What happens is that the value rendered by the s:text is the class name of the object instance (`package.a@xyz`)!

Is this normal? For what I know about Struts2, if no property with that key is found, the rendered value  will be the key (text tag name attribute). Did this ever happened to anyone?

Comment: What version of Struts 2?

Comment: I am using the version 2.3.16.3

Comment: Why do have such property name? It's awful.

Comment: This is not the real use case, it is only for the question purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is normal, because Struts2 parses attributes for OGNL expression, and the result of the expression evaluation will be used as a message key. However the doc says that `searchValueStack` should be used to prevent searches in the value stack. Which one is better decide to you, but I prefer `<s:property value="getText('a')"/>` as an alternative.